# cold crash bottled ale

Tags: cold-crash

I have bottled my ale, it's been bottled for 2 weeks in the warm. I want to drink it in about a week but it's still very cloudy. Should I cold crash to clear it or hope that in another week it will be clear?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, that's a good idea.  Give it a week or 2 cold and it should clear up.

Comment: Thanks. Thought it would be the fastest route but was unsure about doing it in the bottles

Answer (score 2):

The beer will clear with age, but will clear more quickly in cold conditions.

Comment: Usually I wait 3 weeks in a cooler place before drinking but I wanted to drink from Christmas day as would be away, but now we are goings holiday almost a week earlier so need ideally to be ready for then

Comment: @paterbush, if you are travelling with the beer, the sediment will be roused. When you get to your destination, place the beers in the fridge and allow them to settle and clear. What beer did you make? Certain beers should be cloudy.

Comment: I know. I was going to put them in the fridge for a couples days before I drank them. It's a kit beer. Brupaks Almondbury old.